# No such element Exception while sqoop the records into database, Cant parse the input data :''

Tags: sqoop, vertica

I am getting this below error, when trying to sqoop the records to db.
Can anyone guide me here.

```
sqoop export \
    -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=8192 \
    -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx8192m \
    -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=$APP_QUEUE_NAME \
    -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=50000 \
    -Dsqoop.export.statements.per.transaction=100 \
    -Dorg.apache.sqoop.export.text.dump_data_on_error=true \
    --driver $DATABASE_DRIVER \
    --connect $DATABASE_URL \
    --username $DATABASE_USERNAME \
    --password $DATABASE_PASSWORD \
    --direct \
    --export-dir $FILE_DIRECTORY \
    --batch \
    --table $TABLE_NAME \
    --columns $COLUMN \
    --input-null-string '' \
    --fields-terminated-by '|' \
    --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
    -m 40
```

Below is the error from logs,
Let me know if any more details are required.

```
2021-01-05 01:09:51,030 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1606858479635_397560_m_000000_0: Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:122)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: ''
    at customer.__loadFromFields(customer.java:7862)
    at customer.parse(customer.java:7030)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:89)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:864)
    at customer.__loadFromFields(customer.java:7857)
    ... 12 more
```